# Speed up performance on UPDATE of temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure. I'm filling a temp table below, and that's fairly straightforward. However, after that I'm doing some `UPDATE` on it.

Here's my T-SQL for declaring the temp table, `#SourceTable`, filling it, then doing some updates on it. After all of this, I simply take this temp table and insert it into a new table we are filling with a `MERGE` statement which joins on `DOI`. `DOI` is a main column here, and you'll see below that my `UPDATE` statements get `MAX/MIN` on several columns based on this column as the table can have multiple rows with the same `DOI`.

My question is...how can I speed up filling `#SourceTable` or doing my updates on it? Are there any indexes I can create? I'm decent at SQL, but not the best at performance issues. I'm dealing with maybe 60,000,000 records here in the temp table. It's been running for almost 4 hours now.  This is a one-time deal here for a script I'm running once.

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceTable
(
    DOI VARCHAR(72), 
    FullName NVARCHAR(128), LastName NVARCHAR(64), 
    FirstName NVARCHAR(64), FirstInitial NVARCHAR(10), 
    JournalId INT, JournalVolume VARCHAR(16), 
    JournalIssue VARCHAR(16), JournalFirstPage VARCHAR(16), 
    JournalLastPage VARCHAR(16), ArticleTitle NVARCHAR(1024), 
    PubYear SMALLINT, CreatedDate SMALLDATETIME, 
    UpdatedDate SMALLDATETIME, 
    ISSN_e VARCHAR(16), ISSN_p VARCHAR(16), 
    Citations INT, LastCitationRefresh SMALLDATETIME, 
    LastCitationRefreshValue SMALLINT, IsInSearch BIT, 
    BatchUpdatedDate SMALLDATETIME, LastIndexUpdate SMALLDATETIME, 
    ArticleClassificationId INT, ArticleClassificationUpdatedBy INT, 
    ArticleClassificationUpdatedDate SMALLDATETIME, 
    Affiliations VARCHAR(8000),
    --Calculated columns for use in importing...
    RowNum SMALLINT, MinCreatedDatePerDOI SMALLDATETIME, 
    MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI SMALLDATETIME, 
    MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI SMALLDATETIME, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI INT, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI SMALLDATETIME, 
    AffiliationsSameForAllDOI BIT, NewArticleId INT
)

--***************************************
--CROSSREF_ARTICLES
--***************************************
--GET RAW DATA INTO SOURCE TABLE TEMP TABLE..
INSERT INTO #SourceTable 
    SELECT 
        DOI, FullName, LastName, FirstName, FirstInitial, 
        JournalId, LEFT(JournalVolume,16) AS JournalVolume, 
        LEFT(JournalIssue,16) AS JournalIssue, 
        LEFT(JournalFirstPage,16) AS JournalFirstPage, 
        LEFT(JournalLastPage,16) AS JournalLastPage, 
        ArticleTitle, PubYear, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate, 
        ISSN_e, ISSN_p, 
        ISNULL(Citations,0) AS Citations, LastCitationRefresh, 
        LastCitationRefreshValue, IsInSearch, BatchUpdatedDate, 
        LastIndexUpdate, ArticleClassificationId, 
        ArticleClassificationUpdatedBy, 
        ArticleClassificationUpdatedDate, Affiliations,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DOI ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC, CreatedDate ASC) AS RowNum, 
        NULL AS MinCreatedDatePerDOI, NULL AS MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
        NULL AS MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
        NULL AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, 
        NULL AS ArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
        0 AS AffiliationsSameForAllDOI, NULL AS NewArticleId
    FROM 
        CrossRef_Articles WITH (NOLOCK)

--UPDATE SOURCETABLE WITH MAX/MIN/CALCULATED VALUES PER DOI...
UPDATE S
SET MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI, MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, MinCreatedDatePerDOI = T.MinCreatedDatePerDOI, MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI
FROM #SourceTable S
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(UpdatedDate) AS MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI, MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDatePerDOI, MAX(BatchUpdatedDate) AS MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedBy) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedDate) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI, DOI from #SourceTable GROUP BY DOI) AS T ON S.DOI = T.DOI
    UPDATE S
        SET AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
        FROM #SourceTable S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #SourceTable S2 WHERE S2.DOI = S.DOI AND S2.Affiliations <> S.Affiliations)
```

After

Comment: Note: There is no primary key on the temp table, and I don't really think I have a need for one on it.  I'm processing these rows, then merging them into a new table that does have a auto-id on it.

Comment: Have you examined the Execution Plan for your queries yet?

Comment: I just did, and it looks like 90% of the query cost is happening on the insert.  The [Table Insert] for that shows it with a 95% of the cost.  I'm not sure what to do with this knowledge or where to place indexes.  I feel like a bad developer :(  lol

Comment: It's not giving me any missing index recommendations like this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1945/missing-index-feature-of-sql-server-2008-management-studio/

Comment: 4 hours seems like a long time for just 60 mil records -- are you sure it is not miss-reporting expected cost?

Comment: unless crossref_articles is a view?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm clueless...haha.  If I turn the statements on and off, most of the processing does seem to be happening in the initial INSERT.

Comment: Have you tried without the partitioning?

Comment: Mike Nakis, no...I need the partitioning there unless there's another way of achieving the same thing?  i'm putting row numbers there, because when I go to insert rows from this temp table into my actual table, I'm grabbing WHERE RowNum = 1.  The end result is an Article table with one row per DOI (RowNum = 1) and an ArticleAuthor table that contains all the authors for the article from the #SourceTable.  The original data in #SourceTable contains multiple rows per article (DOI), so I'm getting the maxes/mins across them to insert into my main Article table outside of what I posted.

Comment: Not sure what you are tying to do but there has got be a better way.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Frisbee I know! :) 1) Grab all the records from CrossRef_Articles which represents articles w/ authors (with a non-unique ID called DOI that is the article ID).  This table has many rows per article so DOI is not unique, one row for each author. 2) Insert these records into a new table called Articles and ArticleAuthor. Only RowNum = 1 go into Articles since DOI is unique here.  3) Before I insert, I'm doing processing in a temp table to get the max/mins, etc. for each DOI since I'm flattening these rows into 1 row for the new Article table.  it's taking forever with 60 million records.

Comment: That is and implementation not a requirement.

Comment: The requirement is that I take all the records from CrossRef_Articles which contain rows for each article (DOI is the ID for the article, but not unique) and author and split the table into two tables...Article and ArticleAuthors.  Each article can contain multiple authors.  Some of the records have different values in the Updated/Created fields per DOI, so I need to take the MINs/MAXs of those accordingly for the new Article record that needs to created.

Comment: Furthermore, if Affiliations is all the same for all the records within a given DOI, the Affiliations field shall reside in the new Article table.  If the Affiliations aren't all identical for a given DOI, then the Affiliations text will need to reside in the new ArticleAuthors table instead for all those records from that DOI.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are making this a temporary table -- I would make an actual table and then when you are all done delete it.  It would be much easier to data processing on 60 million rows if you make an actual table you can add indexes to.

Comment: @Hogan Temporary tables can have indexes and statistics and in practical sense behave the same way as ordinary tables. The important difference (in this instance) is that they reside in the `tempdb` which can perhaps be put on another drive (which may be a slower drive, or a faster one).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be a faster way to do the update-- hard to say without seeing the execution plan, but it might be running the GROUP BY for every row.

```
with doigrouped AS
(
  SELECT
    MAX(UpdatedDate) AS MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI,
    MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDatePerDOI,
    MAX(BatchUpdatedDate) AS MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedBy) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, 
    MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedDate) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    DOI 
  FROM #SourceTable 
  GROUP BY DOI
)
UPDATE S
SET MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI,
    MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    MinCreatedDatePerDOI = T.MinCreatedDatePerDOI, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI
FROM #SourceTable S
INNER JOIN doigrouped T ON S.DOI = T.DOI
```

If it is faster it will be a couple of orders of magnitude faster -- but that does not mean your machine will be able to process 60 million records in any period of time... if you didn't test on 100k first there is no way to know how long it will take to finish.

Comment: Hogan, I selected the TOP 500k records in the original query and then ran my old UPDATE and new one you suggested.  Both took ~15 seconds each to run, so I can't say I noticed a performance difference.  But your suggestion is certainly a lot cleaner, so I'm keeping it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try:

1. Replace `INSERT` with `SELECT INTO`

Anyway you don't have indexes on your #SourceTable.
`SELECT INTO` is minimally logged, so you must have some speedup here

2. Replace `UPDATE` with `SELECT INTO` another table

Instead of updating #SourceTable you can create #SourceTable_Updates with `SELECT INTO` (modified Hogan query):

```
with doigrouped AS
(
  SELECT
    MAX(UpdatedDate) AS MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI,
    MIN(CreatedDate) AS MinCreatedDatePerDOI,
    MAX(BatchUpdatedDate) AS MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedBy) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, 
    MAX(ArticleClassificationUpdatedDate) AS MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    DOI 
  FROM #SourceTable 
  GROUP BY DOI
)
SELECT
    S.DOI,
    MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxUpdatedDatePerDOI,
    MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxBatchUpdatedDatePerDOI, 
    MinCreatedDatePerDOI = T.MinCreatedDatePerDOI, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedByPerDOI, 
    MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI = T.MaxArticleClassificationUpdatedDatePerDOI
INTO #SourceTable_Updates
FROM #SourceTable S
INNER JOIN doigrouped T ON S.DOI = T.DOI
```

3. Use `JOIN`-ed #SourceTable and #SourceTable_Updates

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things that may help the performance of you insert statement

- Does the `CrossRef_Articles` table have a primary key?  If it does insert the primary key (be sure it is indexed) into your temp table and only include the fields you need to do your calculations.  Once the calculations are done then do a select and join your temp table to the original table on the Id field.  It takes time to write all that data to disk.
- Look at your tempdb.  If you have run this query multiple times then the database or log file size may be out of control.
- Check the fields between the 2 original tables joined to see if the fields are indexed?